# All page links unclickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

So I am working on [this portfolio website thing](http://bronyville.me/bitz/). It's my first time writing HTML and CSS without much of a layout template. 
I seem to have run into an issue that I can't seem to get a hold on. 
The links in the container have become un-clickable. No idea how to fix this since this is my first time with something like this.

I am assuming it has something to do with z-indexing, but I don't know what or where the issue actually is. :s

Thanks in advanced.

To test this, try clicking the link labeled "Getting Started".

Comment: Check in your `console`, it says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #home li:eq(0 a `

Comment: So probably these lines of code `$('#home li:eq(0 a').tab('show')` in `custom.js`

Comment: @Xotic750 Thanks. I fixed that typo, but that isn't the problem. That bit of js doesn't interact with links in the container. But it's fixed for now, so yay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML

```
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <a href="http://google.com"></a>
</div>
```

Your JS **custom.js**

```
$('#home a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault() // <---- this is why clicking it doesn't work
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue!

Comment: Would removing that bit affect anything negatively? It was listed in the API so I don't know if I could have limited it to just its parent element or something.

Comment: Please read the docs I linked to in order to fully understand what that function does.